# XCode 4.3.1 iPad simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode4.3

Does anybody know why home button is missing for iPad simulator only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://openradar.appspot.com/11017007 for the real answer: "Engineer who removed the bezel from scaled iOS Sim not thanked enough, probably"

Answer (score 14):

Its a simple redesign to make more space for the simulator screen. You can trigger the home button from the menu **Hardware** > **Home** Or using the shortcut: <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>.

Comment: was the redesign somehow confirmed by apple? I had missing frames in the simulator before. And the frames appeared after a couple of launches. So I would guess it's a bug,

Comment: I am confused, I imagined the simulator would simulate the actual size of the iPhone, but it makes it nearly 12" high! It's the entire height of the screen, and what iPhone is the height of a MacBook Pro screen? They are usually about half the size, give or take.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is an enhancement at all. This is by far a notorious bug and a bad one. I know that home button action can be reproduced by cmd-H or its double click by doing cmd-H twice, though it could activate the slow motion animations too (annoying!). My point here is that whenever you run the simulator and start testing doing rotations (cmd-arrows), at one point you won't be able to tell if iPad orientation is to the right or to the left!... there's no visual clue whatsoever!
Bad Apple!, bad Apple!

Comment: entirely agree; testing different rotations, you forget which one you are actually looking at.

Answer (score 2):

It appears it is looking at whether or not there is adequate screen resolution to display the bezel.  For example, I have a 17" Macbok pro that I develop on (1920x1200 resolution).  When I launch an iPad development project and the suimulator comes up on my Macbook pro's desktop, no problem, the bezel shows.  But let's say I then drag it over to my external monitor which is 1920x1080, then quit and relauinch the simulator... it comes up without  a bezel.

My co-worker who has a Macbook Pro 13" (lower resolution), never sees the bezel.  I suspect the newer retina Macbook Pros will always show a bezel.

This is of course, al pertaining to the regular, non-retina iPad simulator.  I am not sure if given adequate screen resolution, the iPad retina simulator would show a bezel or not?

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't need more screen space for the simulator with my Thunderbolt 27" display. I'd like the frame back, thank you very much! I also noticed with this version the application icons often show as blank white icons, even for Safari and Photos.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can trigger it from the menu bar (Hardware -> Home).

Comment: Yes, I know but it seems strange to me without home button if iPhone sim. has it :-) Thanks Tim