# Xcode 4.5 New Simulator not displaying properly

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I have just finished installed xCode 4.5 and have been trying to understand the new simulator. I want to test my app in the old screen size and new screen size. However when under the simulator I go to hardware and change the phone size to the 4 inch size, it changes the simulator to take up the full screen, has no home button, is zoomed in, and I have to scroll to navigate which is really frustrating and annoying.

From this

[image]

To this

[image]

Could someone tell me if this is meant to happen? I want to maintain the normal iPhone look with the simulator, that zoomed in scrollable simulator is terrible, looks horrible and makes debugging a pain. I am sure Apple would not allow something this poor looking to be the normal look for the simulator so I am guessing I am doing something wrong.

The other problem with it is, if I am on the home screen where I can see a list of custom apps under normal iPhone screen size, then change it to the 4 inch simulator screen size, the custom apps I installed on the simulator are not showing for some reason.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Edit:

I found I change the scale of the simulator under window and changing it to 50 or 75%. However one problem remains, why is there no home button in the iPhone 5 simulator?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What computer are you working on ? I've got a 13'' MacBook and the same thing occurred to me. Some topics say it is related to your screen resolution, and if your screen is "too small" then the simulator won't see the need in a frame representing the physical device. See Nathan Gopen's answer in [XCode 4.3.1 iPad simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624757/xcode-4-3-1-ipad-simulator). (I also noticed that the frame disappears when you re-scale standard iPhone to 75% or 50%.)

If you need the home button you can find it in Hardware > Home Button, or Shift+Cmd+H. Yeah, I know, it sucks...

Comment: I just scaled the phone down to 50%, but no home button is infuriating, ah well, just gotta get used to using shortcut

Comment: To Gerd below: actually the hints are more and more pointing towards screen resolution. I tested on a 1920x1200 monitor, and 3.5-inch retina iPhone displays with a frame on this monitor. It looks like an iPad, but still, there's a frame and a home button. (Notice that the frame is only visible when you are at 100% scale, no matter which device you choose.)

Comment: Yes, this does seem to be caused by screen resolution.  I have a mediocre monitor hooked up to my MBP.  When I start the simulator on there, I don't see the full phone image, with the home button.  But when I start the simulator on my MBP with retina display, I do see thw full phone image.

Answer (score 6):

This Worked for me:

1. Go to Simulator Menu
2. Go to Hardware
3. Click Device
4. Click IPhone

This will restore the iPhone Simulator frame.

Comment: Yeah, but then the screen size is too small and all of my objects get rearranged.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was...

1. Go to XCode,
2. Open the main XCode menu option
3. Click on "Open Developer Tool"
4. Click on "iOS Simulator"
5. Change to the simulator you want by going to the "Hardware" menu.
6. Close the simulator
7. Run your project again.

XCode was crashing on me when I switched to the non-retina iPad option and this was my solution.

The simulator seems to remember the last hardware option that was chosen.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's related to the screen resolution. I'm running it on 1920x1200 and it's the same. I guess it's simply to reduce effort for Apple since it's not essential for development to have a nice looking simulator. But yes, I agree I loved to see a virtual iPhone as simulator. And it was quite easier to produce screenshots of your Apps for your website.

Zooming or scrolling is of course not required on a 1920x1200 screen.

Comment: I don't see why it would have been difficult to just make a virtual phone for the iPhone 5 as well, all they had to do was increase the size of the current one. Seems kind of lazy of Apple, particularly from a company that prides itself on design.

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me and I did spend a while trying to figure this one out.
By setting the scale to 100% my issue got fixed as Cal said above.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to retina display setting ...

When I started the iOS simulator on my macbook pro (w/rd), the iPhone frame came up. I moved the frame over to my attached monitor and it stayed as an iPhone frame. I shut xCode down.

When I restarted, the iOS simulator started up on my attached monitor and lacked the phone frame, just showing the screen. Scaling up or down did not matter.

I moved the unframed screen over to my laptop screen again, and shut down the simulator. When I started it back up, it started on the laptop screen with the phone frame.

I don't think it is related to resolution so much as retina display.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is long term solution, but the following steps helped me.

> 1. Go to Windows >> Scale
> 2. Select different options as per your wish (I chose 75%)